# Getting UNKOWN_PRODUCER_ID Exception in spring kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am using spring boot 2.1.9 and spring Kafka 2.2.9 with Kafka chained transactions.

I am getting some warning from Kafka producer every time. due to this some time functionality will not work.

I want to know why these errors are coming? is there in config problem?

```
2020-05-04 09:12:35.216  WARN [xxxxx-order-service,,,] 10 --- [ad | producer-8] o.a.k.clients.producer.internals.Sender  : [Producer clientId=producer-8, transactionalId=xxxxx-Order-Service-JOg4T1vFzW4tuc-2] Got error produce response with correlation id 1946 on topic-partition process_event-0, retrying (2147483646 attempts left). Error: UNKNOWN_PRODUCER_ID
2020-05-04 09:12:35.327  WARN [xxxxx-order-service,,,] 10 --- [ad | producer-8] o.a.k.clients.producer.internals.Sender  : [Producer clientId=producer-8, transactionalId=xxxxx-Order-Service-JOg4T1vFzW4tuc-2] Got error produce response with correlation id 1950 on topic-partition audit-0, retrying (2147483646 attempts left). Error: UNKNOWN_PRODUCER_ID
2020-05-04 09:12:53.512  WARN [xxxxx-order-service,,,] 10 --- [ad | producer-6] o.a.k.clients.producer.internals.Sender  : [Producer clientId=producer-6, transactionalId=xxxxx-Order-Service-JOg4T1vFzW4tuc-0] Got error produce response with correlation id 5807 on topic-partition process_submitted_page_count-2, retrying (2147483646 attempts left). Error: UNKNOWN_PRODUCER_ID
2020-05-04 09:12:53.632  WARN [xxxxx-order-service,,,] 10 --- [ad | producer-6] o.a.k.clients.producer.internals.Sender  : [Producer clientId=producer-6, transactionalId=xxxxx-Order-Service-JOg4T1vFzW4tuc-0] Got error produce response with correlation id 5811 on topic-partition process_event-0, retrying (2147483646 attempts left). Error: UNKNOWN_PRODUCER_ID
2020-05-04 09:12:53.752  WARN [xxxxx-order-service,,,] 10 --- [ad | producer-6] o.a.k.clients.producer.internals.Sender  : [Producer clientId=producer-6, transactionalId=xxxxx-Order-Service-JOg4T1vFzW4tuc-0] Got error produce response with correlation id 5816 on topic-partition audit-0, retrying (2147483646 attempts left). Error: UNKNOWN_PRODUCER_ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you might be hitting this [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7190).

> When a streams application has little traffic, then it is possible
>   that consumer purging would delete even the last message sent by a
>   producer (i.e., all the messages sent by this producer have been
>   consumed and committed), and as a result, the broker would delete that
>   producer's ID. The next time when this producer tries to send, it will
>   get this `UNKNOWN_PRODUCER_ID` error code, but in this case, this error
>   is retriable: the producer would just get a new producer id and
>   retries, and then this time it will succeed.

---

**Proposed Solution: Upgrade Kafka**

Now this issue has been [solved](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=89068820#KIP-360:Improvereliabilityofidempotent/transactionalproducer-ProposedChanges) for versions `2.4.0+` so if you are still hitting this you need to upgrade to a newer Kafka version.

**Alternative Solution: Increase retention time & `transactional.id.expiration.ms`**

Alternatively, if you cannot (or don't want to) upgrade then you can increase the retention period (`log.retention.hours`) as well as  `transactional.id.expiration.ms` that defines the amount of inactivity time that needs to pass in order for a producer to be considered as expired (defaults to 7 days).